# How to download an image and put it in a new directory based on the script location?

Tags: python, directory, urllib

Suppose I have this code:

```
import urllib.request

url = 'https://docs.python.org/3/_static/py.png'
file_name = url.split('/')[::-1][0]
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, file_name)
```

When this code running, it will download the *py.png* and name it *py.png*, and store in on the same location of the *.py* file (the code located)

My question is, how can I code it so it downloads the *py.png* in a new folder that is based on the *.py* location.

Suppose my *.py* file location is `desktop\mypylocation\image.py`

I want to create a new folder and store the image inside the new folder so that the path to the image is `desktop\mypylocation\new_folder\py.png`.

Comment: Just as a side note, you can simplify the code for your filename by using `file_name = url.split('/')[-1]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use

```
import os
current_folder=os.getcwd()
```

if you have not changed the directory yet or you are not running the script from a different directory. Otherwise, you can find out the scripts location via

```
import sys
current_folder=sys.path[0]
```

Finally, you can create a new folder via

```
os.mkdir(current_folder+'my_new_folder')
```

In your case this should look like:

```
import sys
import os
import urllib.request

# Define URL
url = 'https://docs.python.org/3/_static/py.png'

# Figure out folder
curr_folder=sys.path[0]

# Create folder
os.mkdir(curr_folder+'/out')

# Get filename
file_name =curr_folder+'/out/'+url.split('/')[::-1][0]
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, file_name)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: the 1st code is good n it make the folder but on wrong directory

Comment: Can you post your current code and an example how you call it?

Comment: the 1st code is good n it make the folder but on wrong directory. lets say home\py folder\pic.py is my .py location, the code above create folder \home\my_new_folder. Instead, what i want it to create \home\py folder\my_new_folder where this will i store the image. Also, this solution for 1st part of my question. The next part is how to write the file and store it inside this my_new_folder.

Comment: I update my question for more explanation. I hope to get full code for the answer

Comment: I updated my answer and specified it for your problem. Tested it on my system and it works.

Comment: thanks. its work. but this problem show how i still dont understand how directory work in python. need to learn more. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

to get the location of the python file use

```
import os

path_of_py_file = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

to create a new folder there

```
os.mkdir(os.path.join(path_of_py_file, 'folder name'))
```

the function `os.path.join` joins parts of path with the correct separator (and makes sure there is only one), it is better than concatenating strings with the assumption that the separator is a backslash